# Expectation of Exit Time of Brownian Motion from Interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am trying to solve the following:

Let $W_t$ be a brownian motion and $a,b >0.$  Define $\tau$ to be the exit time of $W_t$ from $[-a,b]$, that is $$\tau = \inf\{t \ge 0\ :\ W_{t}(\omega) \notin [-a,b]\}.$$  Show that $\tau$ is integrable and compute $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$.

I have seen this stated without proof multiple places that $\mathbb{E}(\tau)=ab.$  What is the logical argument that backs up this statement?  How are we guaranteed $\tau$ is integrable?

Comment: I guess the condition in the definition of $\tau$ should be $W_t(\omega) \notin [-a, b]$.

Comment: Not only is it integrable, all its moments are finite. Once you establish that, use optional stopping on $W$ and $W^2 - [W,W]$ (they are both martingales) to find the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Calculon do you happen to have a reference where they show that all moments of $\tau$ are finite? I can see how the approach below can be used to establish that it's integrable, once we know this the martingale $B_t^4-6tB_t^2+3t^2$ can be used to show that $\tau$ is square integrable and so on. Any other (more feasible) approach?

Comment: @Spaced For every positive integer $P\{\tau \geq n\} \leq \varepsilon^n$ for some $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. You can see this by looking at the increments of BM from $0$ to $1$, from $1$ to $2$ and so on. If $\tau \geq n$ then none of the increments must have exceeded $b + a$ in absolute value. You can use this bound along with the expectation formula for nonnegative random variables 
$E[f(X)] = \int_{R_+}f'(t)P\{X > t\} dt$ for nondecreasing, absolutely continuous $f$ with $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 12):

Truncation is always a good idea to start with. Applying the optional stopping theorem to the bounded stopping time $\tau \wedge n$, we have

$$ \Bbb{E}[W_{\tau \wedge n}] = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \Bbb{E}[W_{\tau \wedge n}^2 - (\tau \wedge n)] = 0. \tag{*} $$

- Even at this point we can infer that $\tau$ is integrable. Indeed, let $c = \max\{a,b\}$ and note that $|W_{\tau \wedge n}| \leq c$. Then applying the monotone convergence theorem to the inequality $\Bbb{E}[\tau\wedge n]\leq c^2$ shows that $\tau$ is integrable.
- Taking $n\to\infty$ to $\text{(*)}$ and applying both the bounded convergence theorem and the monotone convergence theorem gives

  $$ \Bbb{E}[W_{\tau}] = 0, \qquad \Bbb{E}[W_{\tau}^2] = \Bbb{E}[\tau]. $$

  Now the remaining computation is straightforward: Solving the system of equations

  $$ \Bbb{P}(W_{\tau} = -a) + \Bbb{P}(W_{\tau} = b) = 1, \qquad (-a)\cdot\Bbb{P}(W_{\tau} = -a) + b\cdot\Bbb{P}(W_{\tau} = b) = 0 $$

  gives $\Bbb{P}(W_{\tau} = -a) = \frac{b}{a+b}$ and $\Bbb{P}(W_{\tau} = b) = \frac{a}{a+b}$, and plugging this to $\Bbb{E}[W_{\tau}^2] = \Bbb{E}[\tau]$ gives

  $$ \Bbb{E}[\tau] = a^2 \cdot \Bbb{P}(W_{\tau} = -a) + b^2 \cdot \Bbb{P}(W_{\tau} = b) = ab. $$

Comment: This still requires that $\tau$ be a.s. finite.

Comment: @Calculon, I think I showed first that $\tau$ is not only a.s. finite but also integrable.

Comment: You use optional stopping in your first equalities. I might be wrong but I think that requires a.s. finiteness of the stopping time.

Comment: @Calculon, As you pointed out, OST requires quite strong conditions on both the martingale and the stopping time. That is why I applied OST to the truncated stopping time $\tau \wedge n$, which is bounded by $n$.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Would you mind having a look at my question  that is a bit related? Thank you. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4743012/64809