# Symmetric random walk on a lattice: Probability distribution of number of sites that have been visited

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

I'm imagining a $2D$ lattice, but insight into higher dimensional lattices would also be helpful. My question is related to the number of intersections of a random walk on lattice with itself. However, that is not my exact question.

In particular, I want to know the probability distribution describing the number of visited unique grid points after a number $t$ steps. I know that the late-time position, with a little blurring, can be well-described by a gaussian with standard deviation proportional to $\sqrt{t}$, yielding root-mean-square expectation values proportional to $\sqrt{t}$. What I want to know is the behavior of the number of visited grid points. For example, does the number of visited grid points grow like $t$ or $\sqrt{t}$ or some other power law? Ultimately, I want to know asymptotic behavior, like the probability of having visited just a few dozen grid points after a very long time as a function of $t$ and $n$.

To make clear what I mean by visited grid points, I have the following pictures. The steps are ordered from light to dark.

For example, in the drawing below, this specific instantiation of a random walk has visited 7 grid points after 7 steps, which I have colored a light pink. It started at the middle left and ended in the upper right.

[image: Random walk realization]

Here's another realization of a random walk, this time reaching 5 grid points after 7 steps:
[image]

---

To summarize, my question is: What is the probability distribution describing the number of visited unique grid points $n$ after a number $t$ steps on a $2D$ lattice? I am particularly interested in $n/t$ small.

---

Edit: I should add that I anticipate an exponential decay in $t$ at large $t$ at least. The reason for this is that the equivalent $1D$ problem is closely related to the study of exit times from some fixed interval of width $n$, and the probability that an exit time is greater than some $t$ is bounded from above by an exponential decay in $t$: [Exit Time of an Interval Brownian Motion - Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515226/exit-time-of-an-interval-brownian-motion-distribution) discusses this.

Comment: It isn't quite clear to me exactly what you want, but have a look at the references in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07212.pdf

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thank you, the phrase "range of a random walk" is very useful. If the range is $R$, and $k$ is some $O(1)$ number, I am looking for the probability of $R<k$ for large $t$, where $t$ is the number of steps..

Comment: I don't think that exact probability is known. There are good tail bounds, which suffice to prove the law of large numbers, CLT, law of the iterated logarithm, and large deviation principles. The leading order of the number of sites visited is a constant times $n/\log(n)$ in 2D. More detailed tail estimates can be found here: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-30/issue-3/Law-of-the-iterated-logarithm-for-the-range-of-random/10.1214/aop/1029867131.full