# Random walk: tail survival probability of thief surrounded by equally spaced police officers

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, random-walk

In the following problem, we have an unfortunate thief. The thief undergoes a $1d$ simple symmetric random walk on the line starting from the origin at $t=0$.

At the same time, there are police officers that begin their own independent simple symmetric random walks all throughout the lattice - that is, there is one police officer on each lattice point $na, {n \in \mathbb{Z}^*}$ at $t=0$. For example, for $a=4$, there is a police officer on each of the sites $(...,-8,-4,4, 8,12,...)$. For uniformity of notation, call $\tau$ the first collision time between our walker and any police officer. Assume $a$ is even so that the police officers and thief can collide.

What is the asymptotic behavior of the probability $\mathbb{P}(\tau \geq t)$ that the thief survives for at least a time $t$ without any collisions with police officers? I'm also happy with upper bounds demonstrating that the tail probability is at least exponentially suppressed in $\frac{t}{a^2}$; i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\tau \geq t) \leq c_1 e^{-c_2 \frac{t}{a^2}}$ for some appropriate $c_1, c_2>0$.

---

I want to say my motivation for the exponential bounds. Suppose the officers were stationary and not random walking; the question is then about the first exit time $\tau$ from the region $(-a, a)$ starting at the origin. For a Brownian motion started at the origin, the first exit time from this region obeys $\mathbb{P}(\tau >t ) \leq c_1 e^{-c_2 \frac{t}{a^2}}$ for an appropriate pair of constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, as noted in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4098846) by Chris Jangjigian to another question. Allowing the police officers to themselves random walk gives our thief potentially a little bit of breathing room, but I suspect our thief's survival time will nevertheless suffer similar bounds.

---

EDIT: I ran some preliminary numerical checks for a similar model to the above. I find that the tail probability seems fairly well described by $\mathbb{P}(\tau \geq t) \approx c_1 e^{-c_2 \sqrt{\frac{t}{a^2}}}$ at large $t$. It's a lighter tail than any power-law, at least, but note that this is a heavier tail than I expected. I wonder if there's a nice heuristic way to see this stretched exponential behavior. As an aside, I'll note that in the case of [only two officers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758831/asymptotic-distribution-of-the-time-until-collision-of-brownian-motions-started/4760065#4760065), we had an even heavier tail of $\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}$.

Comment: why don't you try it for Two moving officers at [-a,a] first and prove a bound which may help

Comment: @kodlu I agree that that's a fairly natural starting point, and I'll give that a shot. I wonder if having only two diffusing officers might actually yield a heavier tail than an exponential, like a stretched exponential. This would follow if there's a heuristic picture where we get an integral like $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{t}{\xi^2}} e^{-b \xi} d\xi$; I think such a picture might come from exponentially rare trajectories where the officers head in opposite directions away from the origin effectively yielding a growing $a$. I think maybe I'll try asking that as a related question.

Comment: @kodlu I've calculated the asymptotic properties for the case of one thief and two officers in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4760065. The probability of no collision in a time $t$ decays asymptotically as $\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}$. Note that though this tail is large, with the probability decaying as a power-law, I hold out hope that the case of the infinite number of officers will have an exponentially suppressed upper bound.