# Probability of Brownian motion hitting $n$ integers and the expected hit within a time period

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

Given an Ito process $x(t):=\sigma B(t)$ with an unknown constant volatility $\sigma$. Is there a way to estimate $\sigma$ by simply counting the number of times the Ito process hits a lattice with interval length $\delta x$? We know $\mathbf E[x(t)^2]=\sigma^2 t$. For a lattice size $\delta x$, $(\delta x)^2=\sigma^2\delta t$ where $\delta t$ is the time for $x(t)$ to traverse a single lattice step of size $\delta x$. On average $\delta t=\frac Tn$ where $T$ is the total time and $n$ is the number of hits. So it is plausible to conjecture $\big(\frac{\delta x}{\sigma}\big)^2=\frac Tn$. How do we make it rigorous and prove it? The following is a rigorous formulation of this conjecture.

---

Suppose we have a standard Brownian motion $B(t)$ starting from $0$. $\forall \omega$ in the sample space, let the stopping time sequence $\tau(\omega,T):=\big\{t_i|i\in \overline{\mathbf Z^-}, t_0=0, T\ge t_i>t_{i-1}, t_0=0,\,t_i:=\inf\{t:|B(\omega,t)-B(\omega,t_{i-1})|=1\},\,\forall i\in \mathbf N\big\}$. This is the event that the standard Brownian motion $B$ starting from $0$ hitting integers where any two consecutive integers are distinct. What are the probability  $P(n,T)= \text{Pr}(|\tau(\omega,T)|\ge n)$ and $\mathbf E[|\tau(\omega,T)]$?

---

1. Let
   $$\epsilon(\omega, T):=T-\sum_{i=1}^{|\tau(\omega,T)|}t_i(\omega).$$
   Take the expectation. If we conjecture $|\tau(\omega,T)|$ is asymptotically independent of $t_i(\omega)$ $\forall i$ as $T\rightarrow\infty$, we have asymptotically
   $$T\sim \mathbf E[|\tau(\omega,T|]\mathbf E[t_i], \quad T\rightarrow\infty.$$
   [It can be evaluated by the property of a martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2254357/64809) that
   $$\mathbf E[t_i]=1.$$
2. I have a rigorous algorithm relying on the Laplace transform, shown below as an answer, for the computation. I am wondering if there is a simpler expression. Particularly, I wonder if there is a martingale method solution in the vein of, say, [this expect exit time solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2254357/64809).

Comment: Your formulation is somewhat confusing. I guess you defined $\tau(T)$ as the sequence of stopping times in $[0, T]$ corresponding to successively distinct integer steps of a Brownian motion. Then what is your $n$ and $t$ in $\mathbf{E}[n\mid t\leq T]$? I guess you intended $\mathbf{E}[|\tau(T)|]$, the expected length of the sequence $\tau(T)$. Also, in your original attempt, you mentioned something like $$T=\epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i$$ (with the understanding that $n=|\tau(T)|$), but this seems weird because your $t_i$'s look like "arrival times" and not "inter-arrival times".

Comment: @SangchulLee: You are right about the ambiguity of the definitions. I have now corrected them. Please review.

Comment: It is pretty ridiculous to close this question. It is clearly stated and has a clear answer as shown by the answer posted below. Can this person explain his rationale for closing this question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my algorithm to compute the required probability and expectation. I would very much like to know a simpler solution.

We know the probability $\Phi(t):=\text{Pr}(\exists s<t \ni|B(s)|=1)$. Let $\phi(t):=\frac{\partial P(t)}{\partial t}$, since the Brownian motion is strongly Markovian,
\begin{align}
    P(n,t)&:=\text{Pr}(|\tau(\omega,t)|\ge n)  \\
&= \int_{t_1=0}^t d t_1 \phi(t_1)\int_{t_2=0}^{t-t_1}dt_2 \phi(t_2)\cdots \int_{t_i=0}^{t-\sum_{j=1}^it_j}dt_i\, \phi(t_i)\cdots \int_{t_n}^{t-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}t_j}dt_n \phi(t_n).
\end{align}
To facilitate the computation, we take the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) $\mathscr L$ of the above integral and use $s$ as the variable for the resultant function.
\begin{equation}
    \mathscr L[P(n,t)](n,s) = \frac{\mathscr L[\phi](s)^n}s
\end{equation}
The expectation
$$\mathbf E[n=|\tau(\omega,t)|] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(P(n,t)-P(n+1,t)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(n,t),$$
and
\begin{equation}
    \mathscr L\big[\mathbf E[n=|\tau(\omega,t)|]\big](n,s) = \frac1s\frac{\mathscr L[\phi]}{1-\mathscr L[\phi]}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \mathscr L[P(n,t)](n,s) = \frac{\mathscr L[\phi](s)^n}s
\end{equation}
The expectation
$$\mathbf E[n=|\tau(\omega,t)|] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(P(n,t)-P(n+1,t)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(n,t),$$
and
\begin{equation}
    \mathscr L[\mathbf E[n=|\tau(\omega,t)|](n,s) = \frac1s\frac{\mathscr L[\phi]}{1-\mathscr L[\phi]}  \tag1
\end{equation}

Now following the marvelous suggestion of @SangchulLee in the comment below, consider the random variable $M(t):=e^{\sqrt{2s}B(t)-st}$. Since
It is a martingale. By [the optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem),
\begin{align}
    1&=\mathbf E[M(0)]=\mathbf E[M(t)]=\mathbf E[M(t_1)] \nonumber\\
    &= \int_0^\infty \Big(e^{-\sqrt{2s}-st}\text{Pr}(\inf\{u:B(u)=-1\}\in dt)+e^{\sqrt{2s}-st}\text{Pr}(\inf\{u:B(u)=1\}\in dt)\Big)  \nonumber\\
    &= \cosh{\sqrt{2s}}\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\phi(t)dt  \nonumber\\
    &= \cosh{\sqrt{2s}}\;\mathscr L[\phi](s)  \tag2
\end{align}
since $\text{Pr}(\inf\{u:B(u)=-1\}\in dt)=\text{Pr}(\inf\{u:B(u)=1\}\in dt)=\frac12\phi(t)dt$ by symmetry. Substituting Equation (2) into Equation (1), we have
\begin{equation}
    \mathscr L\big[\mathbf E[n=|\tau(\omega,t)|]\big](n,s) = \frac1{s(\cosh{\sqrt{2s}}-1)}.
\end{equation}

Then $\mathbf E[n=|\tau(\omega,t)|]$ is obtained by the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: I can confirm your result. To compliment this, optional stopping theorem applied to the exponential martingale $$M_t=e^{\sqrt{2s}B_t-st}$$ shows that $$1=\mathbf{E}[M_0]=\mathbf{E}[M_{t_1}]=(\cosh\sqrt{2s})\mathbf{E}[e^{-st_1}]=(\cosh\sqrt{2s})\mathscr{L}[\phi](s).$$ Therefore the Laplace transform of the expected length of the sequence $\tau$ is computed as $$\frac{1}{s(\cosh\sqrt{2s}-1)}.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee: Marvelous! Thank you so much! I have two more questions. 1) What if the exit levels are not symmetric, i.e., instead of being $\{\pm 1\}$ but $\{-a,b\}$ for some $a,b>0$?  2)Is there an analytic expression for the inverse Laplace transform of the last expression?

Comment: @SangchulLee: I have edited my answer to incorporate and reference your solution. Please review.